# Add tags to post before it's created

Tags: posts, tags

Is it possible to add tags to a post, prior to its creation?

Say if I have a link "/wp-admin/new-post.php?tags=a,b,c,d" and by clicking it, I want to enter the new-post page with the tags already associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the filter `wp_get_object_terms` like this:

```
function add_object_terms($terms, $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args){
    if (isset( $_GET[ 'tags' ]) && str_replace("'","",$taxonomies) == "post_tag") {
        $newterms = explode(",",$_GET['tags']);
        return array_merge($terms, $newterms);
    } else {
        return $terms;
    }
}
add_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'add_object_terms',1,4);
```

That doesn't work though, maybe the return value has the wrong format, I didn't look it up, instead I tried another filter like this:

```
function add_tags($tags_to_edit, $taxonomy){
    if (isset( $_GET[ 'tags' ]) && $taxonomy == 'post_tag') {
        return $_GET['tags'];
    } else {
        return $tags_to_edit;
    }
}
add_filter('terms_to_edit', 'add_tags',1,2);
```

That works but only if you also use the first filter as well, that's because the second filter won't run if there are no terms to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `load-post-new.php` and `wp_insert_post` actions.

So here's our URL format:

> /wp-admin/post-new.php?add_tags=foo,bar

First, we hook a function to `load-post-new.php` and check if `add_tags` is in the request. If so, we add an action to `wp_insert_post`:

```
function wpa_load_post_new(){
    if ( array_key_exists( 'add_tags', $_REQUEST ) ) {
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpa_insert_post' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpa_load_post_new' );
```

Then on our `wp_insert_post` action, we associate whatever tags were passed with this new post as soon as it's added to the database:

```
function wpa_insert_post( $post_id ){
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $_REQUEST['add_tags'] );
}
```